# Efficient way to select unique records in SAS

Tags: sas

The dataset looks like this:

```
Code    Type     Rating
0001    NULL      1
0002    NULL      1
0003    NULL      1
0003    PA 1      3
0004    NULL      1
0004    PB 1      2
0005    AC 1      3
0005    NULL      6
0006    AC 1      2
```

I want the output dataset looks like

```
Code    Type     Rating
0001    NULL      1
0002    NULL      1
0003    PA 1      4        
0004    PB 1      3        
0005    AC 1      9        
0006    AC 1      2
```

For each `Code`, `Type` has at most two values. I want to select the unique `Code` by summing `Rating`. But the problem is, for `Type`, if it has only one value, the passes its value to output dataset. If is has two values (one has to be `NULL`), then passes the one not equals to `NULL` to output dataset.

The total number of observation `N>100,000,000`. So is there any tricky way to achieve this?

Comment: How many different values of `type` do you have?  Is the data sorted like the above, or not sorted (at least, by `code`)?  What 'not tricky' way are we comparing this to (ie, what do you have now and how long does it take)?

Comment: Few hundreds of `type`. The data is sorted by `code`, then by `type`. I concatenate `type` for each unique `code`. Then look for then non null substring.

Comment: If it's already sorted (ie, you don't do the sort just for this), then the data step solution Keith offers is probably fastest.  If it's not, then it's likely an array solution would be fastest, if it's only a few hundred type.

Comment: It's sorted in a previous step. But it would be better not to sort it first because the executime will increase quite a bit. I should try out an array solution without sorting and a date step with sorted data to see which one is faster?

Comment: You should try various solutions and see which is faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy to do in one SQL step as well.  Just use a CASE...WHEN...END to remove the NULLs and a MAX to then get the non-null value.

```
data have;
input @1 Code 4.
      @9 Type $4.
      @19 Rating 1.;
datalines;
0001    NULL      1
0002    NULL      1
0003    NULL      1
0003    PA 1      3
0004    NULL      1
0004    PB 1      2
0005    AC 1      3
0005    NULL      6
0006    AC 1      2
;;;;
run;

proc sql;
create table want as
    select code, 
        max(case type when 'NULL' then '' else type end) as type,
        sum(Rating) as rating
        from have
        group by code;
quit;
```

If you want the NULLs back, then you need to wrap the select in a `select code, case type when ' ' then 'NULL' else type end as type, rating from ( ... );`, though I would suggest leaving them blank.

Comment: You need to use a summary function (in order for GROUP BY to work).  MAX works on character just as numeric (Z > A, and space=missing is least).  I turn NULL to space, so that it's guaranteed to be least compared to your other value.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is sorted as per your example, then you can achieve this in a single data step.  I've assumed that the NULL values are actually missing, however if not then change [if missing(type)] to [if  type='NULL'].  All this does is sum the Rating values for each Code, then output the last record, keeping the non-null Type.  If your data isn't sorted or indexed on Code then you'll need to do a sort first, which will obviously add quite a bit to the execution time.

```
/* create input file */
data have;
input Code Type $ Rating;
infile datalines dsd;
datalines;
0001,,1
0002,,1
0003,,1
0003,PA 1,3
0004,,1
0004,PB 1,2
0005,AC 1,3
0005,,6
0006,AC 1,2
;
run;

/* create summarised dataset */
data want;
set have;
by code;
retain _type; /* temporary variable */
if first.code then do;
    _type = type;
    _rating_sum = 0; /* reset sum */
end;
_rating_sum + rating; /* sum rating per Code */
if last.code then do;
    if missing(type) then type = _type; /* pick non-null value */
    rating = _rating_sum; /* insert sum */
    output;
end;
run;
```

Comment: This heavily rely on the fact you only have two observations maximum for one code, could you just tell how it would be extended if there is more ?

Comment: Ok, but it was clearly stated that a maximum of 2 observations appeared.  If there were more then it's a simple change to the logic.
if first.code then call missing(_type, _rating_sum);
if not missing(type) then _type=type;
_rating_sum + rating;
etc

Comment: It was not an attack, just a question on how to extend to another case, closer to mine. Sorry if it was offensive.

Comment: Not a problem Anthony.  With hindsight I should probably have posted the solution that covered any number of entries, rather than 2.  There's hardly any extra code to do this and it's more scalable

Answer (score 1):

Given the comments, another possibility presents, the hash solution.  This is memory-constrained, so it may or may not be able to work with the actual data (the hash table isn't very big, but 100M rows might imply 60 or 70M rows in the hash table, times 40 or 50 bytes would still be pretty big).

This is almost certainly inferior to the plain data step method if the dataset is sorted by code, so this should only be used on unsorted data.

The concepts:

- Create hash table keyed on code
- If incoming record is new, add to hash table
- If incoming record is not a new code, take the retrieved value and sum the rating. Check to see if type needs to be replaced.
- Output to dataset.

Code:

```
data _null_;
  if _n_=1 then do;
      if 0 then set have;
      declare hash h(ordered:'a');
      h.defineKey('code');
      h.defineData('code','type','rating');
      h.defineDone();
  end;
  set have(rename=(type=type_in rating=rating_in)) end=eof;
  rc_1 = h.find();
  if rc_1 eq 0 then do;
    if type ne type_in and type='NULL' then type=type_in;
    rating=sum(rating,rating_in);
    h.replace();
  end;
  else do;
    type=type_in;
    rating=rating_in;
    h.add();
  end;
  if eof then do;
    h.output(dataset:'want');
  end;
run;
```