# SAS Most efficient way to eliminate duplicate

Tags: duplicates, sas

For starter I know my problem is similar to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26035448/efficient-way-to-select-unique-records-in-sas)(which is the closest to my question I have found), but with some differences at the same time, hence my new post.

I have a database with an identifier and declarations. Declarations are constructed as identifier + a letter. 
If the idendifier is 123456, declarations would then be "123456A", "123456B" and so on

I would like to select one observation for each identifier, with the declaration that is the one with the last letter, which is of course, not always the same.

I assume I can do that with a proc sort and then another one with nodupkey :

```
proc sort data=have out=have2;
    by identifier declaration /descending;
run;

proc sort data=have2 out=want nodupkey;
    by declaration;
run;
```

but as I have a relatively important database (tens of millions observations) I would like to know the best in sense of both better suited and fastest method if it is another one. 
Typically, if it is possible in one step.

Thanks

Comment: If you have enough memory try Joe's hash solution in the link above which may be faster.

Comment: How many distinct values of `identifier` do you have?

Comment: I have several millions distinct identifiers. To be more precise, most identifiers have only one declaration, about 20% have two, and 1% or so have 3 or more.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a quick solution. It sets only the first observation (in your case the last as you have already sorted by descending). Meaning the rest of the records will not be even loaded into the program data vector. If possible please let me know how it went. I am curious if this would be optimal. I know this to be true only in thoery. I have never tested it myself on a large dataset. 10x

```
data want; 
     do until ( first.identifier ) ; 
         set have; 
         by identifier ;
     end ;
run;
```

Comment: This requires a sort of the data, which the OP is looking to avoid. It's also probably more code than you need (you can just remove the `do\end` and replace with `if first.identifier;` - that would accomplish the exact same thing.)

Comment: I tested it. You are right it still reads all observations like the if condition in your suggestion ... i guess sql then or the nodupkeys as the poster has seggusted

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select 
identifier,
max(declaration) as last_declaration
from have
group by identifier;
quit;
```

Comment: This isn't necessarily a bad solution, but it either does [the hash solution] or [a sort of the data] depending on how the SQL interpreter decides to do it, which seems like a dangerous thing - the former being fast, the latter being oh-so-slow.